# Replace digits in a string by a pattern containing the number of replaced digits

Tags: awk, sed, replace, pipe

I am trying to replace a number consisting of n digits in a filename by a pattern like %03ld or %04ld respectively (depending of the number of digits).

For example:

- `"img/img_000.png"` -> `"img/img_%03ld.png"`
- `"RA20190201_A/img_1030.tif"` -> `"RA20190201_A/img_%04ld.tif"`
- `".../SomeImage_z004.tif"` -> `".../SomeImage_z%03ld.tif"`

As you can see

- the number does not always consist of `0`s only
- it is always followed by the file extension (which can vary)
- the path can contain other numbers which are not relevant (and must remain unchanged)

I think this could be done easily using python (or other languages) but I'm trying to do it by a one-liner with linux build-in tools like `awk` or `sed` using pipes.

I was able to count the digits using `awk` s function `gsub`:

```
> echo "9001_bla/img_0001.png" | awk '{print gsub(/[0-9]/, "")}'
8
```

But I haven't managed to isolate the counting on the relevant part and to perform the actual replacement.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the maximum of potentially occurring numbers?

Comment: Won't it be a problem that the filename for many files ends up being the same?

Comment: In most cases the number will be 3 or 4, I don't think it will be much greater. So lets say 10 would be a good maximum for a generic solution =) 
The resulting string will be used by a program which uses it to read a stack of images (3 digits -> tries to read 999 images).

Comment: is there always a undercore? like :`_numbers.extension`

Comment: Not always, sorry for the misleading examples (I'll update the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it in awk

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  FS=OFS="."
}
match($(NF-1),/[0-9]+$/) {
  $(NF-1)=(substr($(NF-1),1,RSTART-1) "%0" RLENGTH "ld")
} 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution, but:

```
sed "$(seq 10 -1 1 | sed 's@.*@ s/[0-9]\\{&\\}\\(\\.[^\\.]*\\)$/%0&ld\\1/; t @')"
```

- `seq 10 -1 1` - generate numbers from 10 to 1
- The inner `sed`

  - `s` - replace command
  - `@` - separator
  - `.*` - Replace the whole number, ie. each line, by
  - `@` - separator
  - `s/[0-9]\\{&\\}\\.\\([^\\.]*\\)/%0&ld.\\1/; t` - the `&` is substituted for a number and double `\\` are changed into single `\`.
  - `@` - separator
- So the output of inner `sed` is:

  ```
   s/[0-9]\{10\}\(\.[^\.]*\)$/%010ld\1/; t
   s/[0-9]\{9\}\(\.[^\.]*\)$/%09ld\1/; t
   s/[0-9]\{8\}\(\.[^\.]*\)$/%08ld\1/; t
   s/[0-9]\{7\}\(\.[^\.]*\)$/%07ld\1/; t
   s/[0-9]\{6\}\(\.[^\.]*\)$/%06ld\1/; t
   s/[0-9]\{5\}\(\.[^\.]*\)$/%05ld\1/; t
   s/[0-9]\{4\}\(\.[^\.]*\)$/%04ld\1/; t
   s/[0-9]\{3\}\(\.[^\.]*\)$/%03ld\1/; t
   s/[0-9]\{2\}\(\.[^\.]*\)$/%02ld\1/; t
   s/[0-9]\{1\}\(\.[^\.]*\)$/%01ld\1/; t
  ```
- The outer `sed` runs the output of inner sed:

  - `s` - replace
  - `/` - separator
  - `[0-9]\{10\}\(\.[^\.]*\)$` - match 10 numbers followed by a dot, followed by anything but not a dot and match end of line. Save dot and extension in backreference.
  - `/` - separator
  - `%010ld\.\1` - replace it for `%0`, number `10`, `ld`, the matched dot with extension
  - `/` - separator
  - `;` - command separator
  - `t` - if the last `s` command was successful, it branches to beginning of the script. So if one `s` command succeeds, it reads next line and restarts.
  - And that is repeated for each number.

Answer (score 1):

If gnu awk is available, we can make use of FPAT and `gensub()` function to write an one-liner:

```
awk -v FPAT="[0-9]+" '$0=gensub(/(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)(\.[^.]*$)/, 
      "\\1%0"length($NF)"ld\\3","g")'
```

### A little test:

```
kent$  cat f
123_foo_t_1.txt
123_foo_t_12.txt
123_foo_t_123.txt
123_foo_t_1234.txt
123_foo_t_12345.txt
123_foo_t_123456.txt

kent$  awk -v FPAT="[0-9]+" '$0=gensub(/(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)(\.[^.]*$)/, 
      "\\1%0"length($NF)"ld\\3","g")' f
123_foo_t_%01ld.txt
123_foo_t_%02ld.txt
123_foo_t_%03ld.txt
123_foo_t_%04ld.txt
123_foo_t_%05ld.txt
123_foo_t_%06ld.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel echo "{//}/{= s:.*/::;s/\d+/length($&)/e;s//%0$&ld/ =}" :::: file
```

Split each string into the path and the file name. Replace the first set of digits in the filename with their length and then replace that by the required string, finally concatenate the two strings to form the new path and filename.

Alternative GNU sed & Bash:

```
sed -E 's/^(.*\/[^0-9]*)(.*)(\..*)/v=\2;echo \1%0${#v}ld\3/e' file
```